# How does the Schrodinger's potential transformer if the metric conformally transformers?

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics, conformal-geometry

Given Schrodinger's equation
$$
(-\nabla^2+V)\psi=E\psi
$$
and the conformal transformation $\tilde{g}_{mn}=e^{2\phi}g_{mn}$, how does the Schrodinger's potential $V$ transformer if the metric conformally transformers?

Comment: The formula for the Laplace-Beltrami operator under conformal changes of the metric is well-known: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Under_a_conformal_change In particular the change does not introduce a potential term (though it does introduce a first order term). But why do you ask?

Comment: @user225318 The potential contains coordinate variables. I was unsure if the metric were to conformally change then, $V$ would have to be replaced with $\tilde{V}$, where $\tilde{V}\neq V$.

Comment: $V$ is a function from your smooth manifold to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ as you desire. The input is on the level of **points in a smooth manifold**. The metric structure is not part of the input. So of course $V$ doesn't change. Now, if you don't actually mean a conformal change of metric, but perhaps something like "a conformal diffeomorphism of the background manifold", then $V$ will change accordingly. But that is not what you wrote.